# Is the tag 'recommendations' sufficient?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recommendations are off-topic for Webmasters, though there is a 'recommendations' tag. 99% of the questions tagged with 'recommendations' are closed as off-topic, duplicate or closed.

Perhaps we should remove [recommendations](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations).

Comment: Tangent: I'm still in favor of allowing some recommendation questions here.   I answered a question for a user this morning and noticed they had two gold badges.   Those came from two recommendations questions asked several years ago that now have over 10,000 views each.   Recommendation questions can draw lots of visitors to the site.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Then why not make it on-topic?

Comment: I proposed that: [Product recommendations and offsite resource questions, could they be made be on-topic again?](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/product-recommendations-and-offsite-resource-questions-could-they-be-made-be-on) but I found there wasn't much support for it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I understand why recommendations are not allowed, but still there are some valid and honest questions and the poor OP goes away dissatisfied. If there is some list of parameters that define the scope of the answer rather than the question, perhaps that would help. I am in favor of recommendation questions. I do also worry about the slippery slope. But if the answers are moderated, then I cannot see why these question would not be allowed. Of course it is more work for the Mods... ;-) ... you being one of them... alas what to do?

Answer (score 3):

We shouldn't delete it but add a note to it that says that recommendations are off-topic here and refer users to chat instead.

Comment: But what's the use of a tag about a topic which is off-topic?

Comment: They have it on other sites. It's a not-so-effective-but-better-than-nothing way to let users know a topic is off-topic.

Comment: There should be an alternative for that, really.

Comment: The [help] is the primary source for educating users but tags can also be an effective compliment to that.